# Generate a list of recent email senders

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to generate a list of everyone who sent an email to my Outlook account within the past 8 hours,

It is not entering my while loop. I'm sure its a problem with `.Find("[ReceivedTime] > checkTime")`.

```vb
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim myFolder  As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object
Dim senderList As String
Dim checkTime As String

checkTime = Format(Now - 0.3, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") 
 
Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myFolder = myInbox.Folders("Daily Logs")
Set myItems = myFolder.Items
 
Set myItem = myItems.Find("[ReceivedTime] > checkTime")

While TypeName(myItem) <> "Nothing"
    senderList = senderList & myItem.SenderName
    Set myItem = myItems.FindNext
Wend
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find clause needs to compare a time, but as written it is comparing the text "checktime."

This is because the "checktime" is inside the quotes which makes it part of the string rather than outside of the quotes acting as a variable.

Try moving the variable out of the double-quotes and concatenating it with the & operator. Single quotes should be used to qualify the date string (this is how the Find function expects it):

```
Set myItem = myItems.Find("[ReceivedTime] > '" & checkTime & "'")
```

You will be able to readily see the difference if you run this code and look in the immediate window:

```
Debug.Print "[ReceivedTime] > checkTime"
Debug.Print "[ReceivedTime] > '" & checkTime & "'"
```

**Reference**

- [Items.Find Method (Outlook 2010)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869662(v=office.14).aspx)